# Por que no me sale las cabeceras de la JTable

Tags: java, base-de-datos, eclipse, jframe, jtable

Por que no me salen las cabeceras ni los datos en la segunda table. La idea es tener 2 tablas que extraigan la información de una BBDD

**Código**

```
package vista;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import modelo.Alumno;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class MostrarTabla extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable tablaAlumno;
    private JTable tablaGrupo;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MostrarTabla frame = new MostrarTabla();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MostrarTabla() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        iniciarComponente();


        DefaultTableModel tabAl = new DefaultTableModel();
        tabAl.addColumn("NIA");
        tabAl.addColumn("NOMBRE");

        tabAl.addRow(new Object[] {"1", "Pedro"});
        tablaAlumno.setModel(tabAl);
        
        DefaultTableModel tabGrupo= new DefaultTableModel();
        tabGrupo.addColumn("Nombre");
        
        tabGrupo.addColumn(new Object[] {"Primero"});
        tablaGrupo.setModel(tabGrupo);
    }

    private void iniciarComponente() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 530, 439);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(new Color(153, 204, 255));
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblBbddAlumno = new JLabel("Mostar Tabla");
        lblBbddAlumno.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lblBbddAlumno.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        lblBbddAlumno.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblBbddAlumno.setBounds(201, 10, 119, 24);
        contentPane.add(lblBbddAlumno);

//      Alumno x = new Alumno();
        // tablaAlumno = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(x));

        tablaAlumno= new JTable();
        contentPane.add(tablaAlumno);
        tablaAlumno.setBounds(23, 48, 241, 205);
        
        tablaGrupo = new JTable();
        tablaGrupo.setBounds(300, 44, 191, 217);
        contentPane.add(tablaGrupo);

    }
}
```

**Diseño**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para `tabGrupo` no haces `addRow()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***¿Por que no veo las cabeceras?***

Por defecto una `JTable` va a ajustarse al tamaño de su contenedor haciendo que el *scrolling* sea innecesario.

Por tal motivo normalmente una `JTable` está ubicada dentro de un `JScrollPane` en donde ademas de poderse deslizar con *scroll bars* a traves del cuerpo de la tabla tambien permite ver su encabezado.

```
    tablaAlumno= new JTable();
    JScrollPane sp1=new JScrollPane(tablaAlumno);
    contentPane.add(sp1);
    sp1.setBounds(23,48,241,205);
    
    tablaGrupo = new JTable();
    JScrollPane sp2=new JScrollPane(tablaGrupo);
    sp2.setBounds(300, 44, 191, 217);
    contentPane.add(sp2);
```

***¿Y mis datos en la segunda tabla?***

Quiza la confusion esté en que se estan pasando los datos via [`addColumn`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addColumn(java.lang.Object)) que es el que aplica encabezados al modelo de tabla en vez de usar el metodo [`addRow`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) para establecer la informacion en las filas de la tabla.

```
    //tabGrupo.addColumn(new Object[] {"Primero"});
    tabGrupo.addRow(new Object[] {"Primero"});
```